# VBA + IE choose index in context drop down that contain buttons that open pop-ups?

Tags: vba, excel, drop-down-menu, dojo

I'm trying to use VBA to click on a context drop down menu that contains links that open pop up boxes.  However, using getElementById and .selectedIndex don't seem to be working as i Can't seem to find the right ID.

Also, when I click to inspect the context menu it gives me this code which doesn't seem right:

```
<div data-dojo-attach-point="rowNode" data-dojo-attach-event="onclick:_onClick" class="agsjsTOCRootLayer" title="Source Features" style="padding-left: 0px;">
```

Here is some source code for the dialog box that contains the drop downs with clickable buttons that open new dialog boxes:

```
<div id="dijit__Widget_1" widgetid="dijit__Widget_1">
<div class="agsjsTOCNode" id="TOCNode_id_source_features"widgetid="dijit__Templated_38">
<div data-dojo-attach-point="rowNode" data-dojo-attach-event="onclick:_onClick" class="agsjsTOCRootLayer" title="Source Features" style="padding-left: 0px;">
<span data-dojo-attach-point="contentNode" class="agsjsTOCContent">  
<span data-dojo-attach-point="checkContainerNode"><img>
src="http://js.arcgis.com/3.13/dojo/resources/blank.gif" alt="" data-dojo-attach-point="iconNode" class="dijitTreeExpando dijitTreeExpandoClosed agsjsTOCIcon">
<div class="dijit dijitReset dijitInline dijitCheckBox" role="presentation" widgetid="dijit_form_CheckBox_16">
<input type="checkbox" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" class="dijitReset dijitCheckBoxInput" data-dojo-attach-point="focusNode" data-dojo-attach-event="ondijitclick:_onClick" value="on" tabindex="0" id="dijit_form_CheckBox_16" style="user-select: none;">
</div>
```

Source Features

I'm trying to click on a drop down menu that appears only if your mouse is hovering over it to the right of the Source Feature title.

I've tried using the index selection code, but can't seem to find the right ID.  Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately the website is private so I can't give a link here.

Comment: have you tried this id: `dijit_form_CheckBox_16`?

Comment: I'm not trying to choose to checkbox.  I'm trying to select a dropdown arrow  that only appears when you hover your mouse over it.